Hardwood floor burn in
We had a black lamp on our hardwood floors with in floor heating stay in one place for a long time, and when we moved it we found the following burn in.
Is this repairable? What is the general procedure for something like this?
https://imgur.com/a/Rsosdhp

looks like water damage

I agree with Jasen, that looks like water was more involved than heat.  I bet something was spilled and not cleaned up under the lamp base.  Sanding and refinishing the stain may remove most of the discoloration.  A little bleach & water on the ends of the darker black boards may kill the organism and brighten that.  If you aren't confident in refinishing, call a pro.
